# Why is my hibiscus plant leaves droping ,turning yellow and producing small flowers even when it has been watered?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, shrubs, hibiscus

My hibiscus plant's leaves are drooping, and yellow and the flower size has shrinked substantially. Yellow leaves are present at bottom and middle of the plant. The plant is 4 feet tall, and the pot is 1 foot tall with a diameter of 10 inches approx. It has small leaves but most of those small leaves have turned yellow. Moreover, its winters(mid of November) here in Delhi,India .

I have no idea of what is going on. It's foliage has also reduced. I can't figure out if there is a problem of watering (since I am watering the plant only when the soil feels dry.) Or is it because of the container size or could it be due to winter season  or is it pest or fungus.

I had fertilized it in the beginning of October. And it is placed in my balcony with partial lighting ( and direct evening sunlight )

Comment: A photo of the plant and its pot would be helpful -how long has it been in the same pot?

Comment: And does the pot have drainage?

Comment: Jurp, yes it has sufficient drainage holes 5-6